# Android : How to store app data in SD card using air

Tags: android, air, external

Application data is stored in the phone internal memory, even the android installation location is "preferExternal" and enabled "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android permission in manifest. As per documentation, i  have to used either "userDirectory" or "documentsDirectory". Even though cant able to store the app data into external memory. How to do it?

Comment: *air* means *adobe air*?

Answer (score 0):

use this way for getting path ...

```
  //Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().xyzpaths()
  // get path like this

        File log = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Log.txt");
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log.getAbsolutePath(), false));
            out.write(new Date().toString());
            out.write(" : \n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error opening Log.", e);
        }
```

Comment: This question is about Adobe AIR, not native Android Java.

Comment: can you tell me how to go with adobe air, since i have tried with userDirectory and documentsDirectory. when i am seeing the app data size in app settings, size got increased only in internal data and external data is always 0.